# How can I join two array of documents with different partition and the same collection?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have two partitions in one Collection and try take array of Positions for some Supplier Orders like in code below but its not working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM p
WHERE p.partition = "Positions" and p.SupplierOrder_id in 
(SELECT value so.id from so where so.OfferId = "883ed603-69a9-4a81-a144-93957fc5a2e2" and so.partition = "SupplierOrders")
```

and everything is all right, if I change

`(SELECT value so.id from so where so.OfferId = "883ed603-69a9-4a81-a144-93957fc5a2e2" and so.partition = "SupplierOrders")`

to

`("84abab45-d60e-48b0-9e94-4420bb436196", "0be54840-bbd3-42ea-a120-949edb36a4f6")`

like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM p
WHERE p.partition = "Positions" and p.SupplierOrder_id in 
("84abab45-d60e-48b0-9e94-4420bb436196", "0be54840-bbd3-42ea-a120-949edb36a4f6")
```

P.s. this query if run its separated

```
SELECT value so.id from so where so.OfferId = "883ed603-69a9-4a81-a144-93957fc5a2e2" and so.partition = "SupplierOrders"
```

return

```
[
    "84abab45-d60e-48b0-9e94-4420bb436196",
    "0be54840-bbd3-42ea-a120-949edb36a4f6"
]
```

Can anybody help me with my problem? 
P.S. Of cause I understand that its looks like relational db and I can solve my problem by two queries.

Comment: i dont think a query can be limited to 2 partitions? only cross partition or a single partition queries exist?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand your question, but what i can say is that, you can limit the query to certain logical partitions by specifying the corresponding partition keys in your query filter.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you made a mistake with sql query syntax.In fact,you already posted in your question. You said you used `()`,it works right.But no luck with sub query `select value .....`.Because `in` operator should be used with `()`,not array `[]`.However, sub query outputs array `[]`.

I tried below sql which uses Array_Contains method,but i still get 0 row.

```
SELECT p.id,p.name
FROM p
WHERE p.partition = "Positions" and 
array_contains((SELECT value p.id from p where p.OfferId = "***" and p.partition = "SupplierOrders")
,p.SupplierOrder_id,true)
```

After researching official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery#exists-expression),i believe subquery can't be implemented with Array_Contains operator. So,as a workaround, i think you could use 2 sqls to achieve the goal. The first one sql outputs the `array []`,and send the array into second sql as parameter.